# update rows and drop few rows in grouped data based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have the following dataframe which has 4 columns. Lets call it df.

```
    ID  Start transfer  Finish transfer Ward
0   7685933 04/11/2015 12:07    05/11/2015 12:49    General surgery
1   7685933 05/11/2015 12:49    11/11/2015 14:42    Anestesiology
2   7685933 11/11/2015 14:42    11/11/2015 16:12    Anestesiology
3   7685933 11/11/2015 16:12    18/11/2015 21:24    General surgery
4   7685933 18/11/2015 21:24    02/01/2016 06:45    ICU
5   7690142 06/11/2015 17:24    30/11/2015 18:11    Internal Medicine
6   7690142 30/11/2015 18:11    02/12/2015 17:04    Internal Medicine
7   7690142 02/12/2015 17:04    03/12/2015 20:40    Internal Medicine
8   7690142 03/12/2015 20:40    11/01/2016 18:00    Internal Medicine
9   7691888 08/11/2015 16:28    16/11/2015 17:11    Internal Medicine
10  7691888 16/11/2015 17:11    20/11/2015 18:13    Internal Medicine
11  7691888 20/11/2015 18:13    04/01/2016 18:02    Internal Medicine
12  7691888 04/01/2016 18:02    04/01/2016 21:13    Internal Medicine
```

Now I want to group the data based on the column 'ID' and then look for similar consecutive Wards where the 'Finish Transfer' of a Ward is same as the 'Start Transfer' of the next consecutive similar Ward name. Once thats is figured out, I need to copy the Finish transfer entry from the last consecutive ward row and update the first entry for that specific ward with that value. For example, row1 and row2 at index 1 and 2 both have similar ward and if you look at the Finish Transfer entry of row1 (index1), it is similar to Start Transfer of row2(index2). Ward is also same. What I want is to have only one row of this consecutive data where start transfer is the one from row1 and Finish transfer is from row2.

I want the following as output (may be in a new dataframe):

```
    ID  Start transfer  Finish transfer Ward
0   7685933 04/11/2015 12:07    05/11/2015 12:49    General surgery
1   7685933 05/11/2015 12:49    11/11/2015 16:12    Anestesiology
2   7685933 11/11/2015 16:12    18/11/2015 21:24    General surgery
3   7685933 18/11/2015 21:24    02/01/2016 06:45    ICU
4   7690142 06/11/2015 17:24    11/01/2016 18:00    Internal Medicine
5   7691888 08/11/2015 16:28    04/01/2016 21:13    Internal Medicine
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You've described what you want, but not what went wrong when you tried to do it, or how your attempts to overcome those problems failed.  Right now it sounds like you just have a specification, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(['ID','Ward']).agg({'Start transfer':'first','Finish transfer':'last'}).reset_index()
Out[151]: 
        ID               Ward    Start transfer   Finish transfer
0  7685933      Anestesiology  05/11/2015 12:49  11/11/2015 16:12
1  7685933    General surgery  04/11/2015 12:07  18/11/2015 21:24
2  7685933                ICU  18/11/2015 21:24  02/01/2016 06:45
3  7690142  Internal Medicine  06/11/2015 17:24  11/01/2016 18:00
4  7691888  Internal Medicine  08/11/2015 16:28  04/01/2016 21:13
```

Update

```
df.assign(Key=(df.Ward.shift()!=df.Ward).cumsum()).groupby(['ID','Ward','Key']).agg({'Start transfer':'first','Finish transfer':'last'}).reset_index().sort_values('Key')
Out[181]: 
        ID               Ward  Key    Start transfer   Finish transfer
1  7685933    General surgery    1  04/11/2015 12:07  05/11/2015 12:49
0  7685933      Anestesiology    2  05/11/2015 12:49  11/11/2015 16:12
2  7685933    General surgery    3  11/11/2015 16:12  18/11/2015 21:24
3  7685933                ICU    4  18/11/2015 21:24  02/01/2016 06:45
4  7690142  Internal Medicine    5  06/11/2015 17:24  11/01/2016 18:00
5  7691888  Internal Medicine    5  08/11/2015 16:28  04/01/2016 21:13
```

Comment: Hi Wen, This one line of code seems to be working fine for most of the data but if you look at your result row 1 (index 1), General surgery data is now merged for that specific ID. However, I should have two separate entries for General surgery because Finish transfer of the first entry (index 0 of my data) is not the same as the start transfer of row3 (index 3). Any further improvement?

Comment: Hi Wen, I just tested the update code and it works perfect. Great Thanks. Just for the purpose of understanding, can you explain what is actually happening in the code especially with the use of key in the first part  df.assign(Key=(df.Ward.shift()!=df.Ward).cumsum())? One more small thing. In the actual dataset, I have like 22 columns but when I run your code and save the result into another dataframe, I only have 5 columns (similar to the results of the update code). Is there a way that I can keep the data from other columns of the actual dataframe in the resulting new dataframe df_new?

Comment: I do the following: df_new=df.assign(Key=(df.Ward.shift()!=df.Ward).cumsum()).groupby(['ID','Ward','Key']).agg({'Start transfer':'first','Finish transfer':'last'}).reset_index().sort_values('Key')

Comment: @HT121 df.assign(Key=(df.Ward.shift()!=df.Ward).cumsum()), this is record Ward  changes , if it changes count = count+1 , then we can fobiden the previous code error result